# Adding a list to my x-bar does not work

Tags: r

I want to add list to an x-bar. So im doing:

```
 data_total <- read.csv2("graph_medewerkers.csv", header = T) #grab excel
 data <- data_total$PERCNG #getting one column
 head(data) => 


 [1] 4.74  8.71  7.01

 qcc(data, type="xbar.one", center = 2)
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
 Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
 non-numeric argument to binary operator
 In addition: Warning message:
 In mean.default(statistics) :
 argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I dont really understand whats going wrong. Cause when I do:

```
data <- c(4.74, 8.71, 7.01) and then
qcc(data, type="xbar.one", center = 2)
```

It does work. Any thoughts on whats is triggering the error? There are no numeric values in my set....

Comment: You are assuming that everyone here knows where the function `qcc` comes from and in the absence of that context what exactly "an x-bar" is.

Comment: Please show `str(data)`.

Comment: I agree with @Roland that information on `str(data)` would be helpful here. Maybe the problem can be simply solved by using `qcc(as.numeric(data), type="xbar.one", center = 2)`.